# Is the Evaluation map of an R-Module of rank 1 and hom injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, module-isomorphism

This is in context of a larger problem of showing that the dual of an invertible sheaf is invertible on a scheme.

I want to show that given a free R-module A of rank 1, the standard evaluation map given by

$A \otimes Hom_R(A,R) \rightarrow R \\
a \otimes f \mapsto f(a)$

is an isomorphism. Surjectivity is trivial but I'm having some trouble with injectivity.

I tried a proof by contradiction by assuming a non zero  r and non zero f such that $f(r) = 0$ and show that since there would exist $q \in A$ s.t $f(q) = b$ for nonzero $b$. but after a lot of pushing symbols around, I didn't get anywhere.

Since A is of rank 1, I know it is sufficient to show that the same evaluation map from $R \otimes Hom_R(R,R) \rightarrow R$ is an isomorphism. But I ran into the same issue. Since the tensor product is the fiber product in the case of R-modules, I tried picking a clever R-module S and morphism from S to $R \otimes Hom_R(R,R)$ to see the injectivity of the above map. The obvious choices are clearly $R$ and $Hom_R(R,R)$ but I didn't see why they worked (If they do).

Edit: Any ring mentioned is a commutative ring with identity.

I'm still very inexperienced with this so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is $R$ a unital ring?

Comment: Yes. It is. Commutative ring with identity.

Comment: I think then that the evaluation map decomposes as the composite of the isomorphisms $R\otimes_R\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,R)\simeq R\otimes_R R\simeq R$ via $a\otimes f\mapsto a\otimes f(1)\mapsto af(1)=f(a)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's show that the evaluation map $R \otimes \operatorname{Hom}(R, R)$ is injective by producing an inverse explicitly.

The inverse will simply send $r \rightarrow r \otimes \text{id}_R$.

The composition of the maps then sends $$r \otimes f \rightarrow f(r) \rightarrow f(r) \otimes \text{id}_R$$

Note that the $f(r)$ can pass from left to right and then the $r$ can pass back to the left, i.e.

$$1 \otimes \text{id}_R f(r) = 1 \otimes f(r) = r \otimes f$$